# Error de clase, consulta php, no puede ser convertido a entero

Tags: php

Hola estoy haciendo por medio de php una paginacion pero se me presento un problema cuando quiero contar el numero de registros y hago la consulta no puedo usarlo para sacar el numero de paginas.

Codigo en php:

```
<?php

require_once 'database.php';
$database_connection = database_connect();
$title='hola';

$content='<div>';

//user input
$page = isset($_GET['page']) ? (int)$_GET['page'] : 1;
$perPage = isset($_GET['per-page']) && $_GET['per-page'] <= 50 ? (int)$_GET['per-page'] : 5;

//Positioning
$start = ($page > 1) ? ($page * $perPage) - $perPage : 0;
$art = $database_connection->query("SELECT id FROM coffee");
//Query
$articles = $database_connection->prepare("SELECT id FROM coffee LIMIT {$start},{$perPage}");

$articles->execute();
$articles = $articles->fetchAll();

$total = $database_connection->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM coffee");

//pages
$pages = ($total/$perPage);


$content .= '<div>';


include 'Template_1.php';
?>
```

Basicamente mi duda es aqui `$pages = ($total/$perPage);` como podría hacer la conversion para que cuando hago la consulta:

```
$total = $database_connection->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM coffee");
```

sea un entero y no un resultset.

Comment: disculpa por lo de string l oque queria decir que la consulta 'SELECT...' es un string me comi medio parrafo y escribe esa parrafada disculpa

Answer (score 3):

Sin saber exactamente lo que es `$database_connection`, me voy a arriesgar a adivinar que:

```
$total = $database_connection->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM coffee");
```

lo que está devolviendo `$database_connection->query` es un resultset y no un valor en concreto, por lo que `$total` no contendrá un número entero, sino un resulset que aún tendrás que procesar.

Si estás usando PDO, podrías hacer algo como esto (no lo he probado y puede fallar):

```
$resultado = $database_connection->query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM coffee");
$fila = $resultado->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$total = $fila["total"];

$pages = ($total/$perPage);
```

Comment: esque el problema que cuando hago eso no puedo obtener el numero de paginas que tendra mi paginacion: $total = $database_connection->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM coffee"); cuando hago esto : $pages = ($total/$perPage);

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que falla?

Comment: Notice: Object of class PDOStatement could not be converted to int

Comment: He editado el código para que se ajuste a PDO en lugar de MySQLi. Pruébalo y dime que tal va

Comment: hola disculpa no entiendo muy bien de perpage <=50 a que se refiere un saludo y gracias, ahora puedo mostrar facilmente cuando hago una consulta con count gracias

Comment: estoy un poco confundido con la paginacion lo que me hace articles es mostrarme por cada pagina un article pero quiero definir desde perpage el numero de paginas para cada numero de registros

Comment: ¿No entiendes tu propio código?

Comment: No es eso esque use perPage la funcion isset, sin embargo yo puedo ponerle el numero por cada pagina por ejemplo $perPage =5; entonces no veo necesario utilizar el isset en mi caso

Comment: Lo del isset para el perPage es para asegurarse que si tiene un valor sea como máximo 50. Si se le pasa un valor, se comprueba si es menor que 50 y se asigna ese; sino, será 5 por defecto.

Comment: algun consejo para definir las diferentes paginas en mi paginacion gracias ya que me esta resultando mas complicado de lo que pensaba

Comment: ok disculpen no esque no entienda sino que queria matizar unas cosas y puedo que al no ser expertos pues tome por alguna parte de otros tutoriales y intente entender de otros, de todas maneras puedo decir que si respondio gracias y que en lo que respecta al codigo publicado lo entiendo perfectamente un saludo y gracias

Comment: ya lo solucione era una tonteria esta mandando a otra ruta asi como que no me pagina jaja